# How to use a class as a type for properties of another class in typescript?

Tags: class, typescript

I am new to typescript. I have defined some classes. I have used them as a type for the property of another class. e.g:

**fileone.ts**

```
export class A {
   propertyOne: string;
   propertyTwo: string;
}
```

Now i have another class B in another file:

**filetwo.ts**

```
import { A } from './fileone';
export class B {
    myProperty: A;
    mySecondProperty: string;
}
```

I have instantiated this class B in another file. 
I have the following code:

**myapp.ts**

```
import { B } from './filetwo';
export class C {
    let myObj: B = new B();
    myObj.myProperty.propertyOne = 'hello';
    myObj.myProperty.propertyTwo = 'world'';
    console.log(myObj);
 }
```

Now when i try to set the property of A through B, it say the following error:

`Cannot set the property "propertyOne" of undefined`

Can we not do this like in java? And please explain why i cannot do what i am doing right now. And what is the correct approach for this. Please do not just give me solution to my problem but also an explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have set the correct type of your `myProperty` member but this variable is not initialized by just declaring the type. So you are trying to set a property `propertyOne` on an `undefined` variable on your instance of B.

If you want to have it initialized correctly, you need to do this manually in your class B:

```
export class B {
  myProperty: A;
  constructor() {
    this.myProperty = new A();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`myObj.myProperty` is type of `A` which is not defined yet, so you should initialize it

```
myObj.myProperty = new A();
```

then use it

Answer (score 0):

It may seem out of scope, but I had the same issues except I was using VueJs also. So, to piggy back off of Andreas Jägle answer. This minor variation worked for me except I had to add super(); to my class constructor.

**importmodule.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue'; 
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'; 
import { MyProfile } from '../../data';

interface CurrentUser {
    name: string;
    title: string;
    groupName: string; }

@Component 
export default class Profile extends Vue {
    profile: MyProfile;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.profile = new MyProfile();
    } }
```

**data.ts**

```
export interface IPro {
    name: string;
    title: string;
    groupName: string;
}

export class MyProfile implements IPro {
        name = "User";
        title = "Title";
        groupName = "Group";
    }
```